# I want to convert paper.js Examples from paperscript to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, paperjs

I am Japanese and I apologize for my unnatural English, but I would appreciate it if you could read it.
I learned how to convert paperscript to javascript from the official documentation.
Its means are as follows

1. Change the type attribute of the script tag to text/paperscript. `<script type="text/paperscript" src="./main.js"></script>`
2. Enable Paperscope for global use. 　`paper.install(window)`
3. Specify the target of the canvas. `paper.setup(document.getElementById("myCanvas"))`
4. Write the main code in the onload  `window.onload = function(){ /* add main code */ }`
5. Finally, add `paper.view.draw()`
6. The onFrame and onResize transforms as follows. `view.onFrame = function(event) {}`
7. onMouseDown, onMouseUp, onMouseDrag, onMouseMove, etc. are converted as follows. `var customTool = new Tool(); customTool.onMouseDown = function(event) {};`

I have tried these methods, but applying these to the Examples on the paper.js official site does not work correctly.
The following code is the result of trying these.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
paper.install(window);
console.log("run test")
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var customTool = new Tool();
window.onload = function(){
  paper.setup(myCanvas)

  var points = 25;

  // The distance between the points:
  var length = 35;

  var path = new Path({
    strokeColor: '#E4141B',
    strokeWidth: 20,
    strokeCap: 'round'
  });

  var start = view.center / [10, 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < points; i++)
    path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));

  customTool.onMouseMove=function(event) {
    path.firstSegment.point = event.point;
    for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
      var segment = path.segments[i];
      var nextSegment = segment.next;
      var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
      vector.length = length;
      nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
    }
    path.smooth({ type: 'continuous' });
  }

  customTool.onMouseDown=function(event) {
    path.fullySelected = true;
    path.strokeColor = '#e08285';
  }

  customTool.onMouseUp=function(event) {
    path.fullySelected = false;
    path.strokeColor = '#e4141b';
  }
  view.draw();
}
```

The original paperscript can be found [here](http://paperjs.org/examples/chain/).

What is the problem with this code?
Thank you for reading to the end!

Comment: The main issue was the vector math operations between paperscript and javascript. see below answer

Answer (score 2):

The `var vector` in the for loop is not getting the correct values in your code. Change the math operators and it will work like the paperjs demo.

Math operators (`+ - * /`) for vector only works in paperscript. In Javascript, use `.add()` `.subtract()` `.multiply()` `.divide()`. see http://paperjs.org/reference/point/#subtract-point

```
// paperscript
segment.point - nextSegment.point

// javascript
segment.point.subtract(nextSegment.point)
```

Here's a working demo of your example

```js
paper.install(window);
console.log("run test")
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
var customTool = new Tool();
window.onload = function() {
  paper.setup(myCanvas)

  var points = 15; //25

  // The distance between the points:
  var length = 20; //35

  var path = new Path({
    strokeColor: '#E4141B',
    strokeWidth: 20,
    strokeCap: 'round'
  });

  var start = view.center / [10, 1];
  for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));
  }

  customTool.onMouseMove = function(event) {
    path.firstSegment.point = event.point;
    for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
      var segment = path.segments[i];
      var nextSegment = segment.next;

      //var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
      var vector = segment.point.subtract(nextSegment.point);

      vector.length = length;

      //nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
      nextSegment.point = segment.point.subtract(vector);
    }
    path.smooth({
      type: 'continuous'
    });
  }

  customTool.onMouseDown = function(event) {
    path.fullySelected = true;
    path.strokeColor = '#e08285';
  }

  customTool.onMouseUp = function(event) {
    path.fullySelected = false;
    path.strokeColor = '#e4141b';
  }
  view.draw();
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0
}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
  <!-- you can add this back in -->
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script> -->
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- set any size you want, or use CSS/JS to make this resizable -->
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="150"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```